# Woocommerce filter products by dynamic/static keys

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce business logic requires:

1. Customer need defined, where and when for him need to ship order.
2. In Product metas I have for each product defined how many days need for shipment for specify geo zone.
   These logic works well, but:
   Problem starts, when i need something most powerful than [WP_Meta_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) to create custom filter, like: CAN Deliver or CAN'T Deliver

Product have static selector (key) from meta, but second dynamic selector from WC()->session. 
Only when customer enter his inputs. I know final meta value as custom filter variable.

So how to solve this to make query like custom product filter who fits in standard WC loop template:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
            <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>
                <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```